# Cannot read property '$type' of null

Tags: breeze

I'm using the default JsonResultsAdapter after after doing a saveChanges call to the server, the entity that got saved is returned and parsed through the adapter and for some reason a null node is being passed into the visitNode method, causing the whole thing to throw an error. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Edit: I should note that this only started happening when I updated to 1.3.1. I was running on 1.2.8 fine.

Comment: I can't repro this, can you give me any addl information. Is this using the WebApi dataServiceAdapter or the OData dataServiceAdapter?

Comment: I rolled back to an earlier version of breeze, and did the upgrade again and that fixed things. Apparently something went wrong when I updated the first time, but I'm working now. Thanks!